# Blazor Web Assembly and Custom API Routes

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api-routing, blazor-webassembly

I need a custom route to an API on Project.server

I have 3 GET Api Requests
Locations 
Locations/id

I need to Create a 3rd one, a Custom one

GetLocationsByCompany with a the ID of the company passed though.
Company/id

I have this

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetLocationsByCompany")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<EntityLocation>>> GetLocationsByCompany(string id)
```

this is how i call it, LocationsController is the controller

```
var locations = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Locations[]>("api/Locations/GetLocationsByCompany/" + ID);
```

Web Assembly just gives me the error, 500 not very helpful, the other message is shows is "There is Nothing to Show here"

Debugging in Chrome Does show the correct ID Being sent and the and the request looks good.

The brake point on the action in the controller is not getting hit. Therefore it leaves me with the thought my routing is wrong.

where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parameters, make sure to include a placeholder in the template value, for example `{id}` in:

```
[HttpGet("GetLocationsByCompany/{id}")]
```

Comment: Thanks ! this works, spent the whole afternoon scratching my head around this. very grateful for your help !